# Token are not working in my content type fields (they show as they are)

Tags: tokens

I need to have display on all pages a specific token. I have my own content types and I would like fill them with my tokens as well.
I noticed the tokens shows up as they are not as their values.

How can I make tokens display correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [Token Filter](http://drupal.org/project/token_filter) module.

I'm not sure if it will do exactly what you want, but it is a way to have Tokens rendered in your node, if at least in the body text of the node.